# Same mountpoint for several external drives

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, autofs

I'd like to have 2 eSATA drives, which can be hot swapped, mounted at the same mountpoint. Only one of them will every be mounted at a time.

Since they may not be attached when the computer boots, having them in `/etc/fstab` is not a good option, I presume. I tried using `autofs` for this, but it does not seem to support multiple drives with the same mountpoint.

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/865000/two-external-hard-drive-on-same-mounting-point-in-fstab-but-only-one-should-be) is about the same topic, but using `fstab`. It *seems* like there is no solution for what I want, other than writing my own script and manually running that after inserting one of the drives.

I have an `auto.mine` file that looks like this. It works when I have one but not both of the lines enabled. I can see that it might be a bad idea in general to set up the same mountpoint for multiple disks, but I would still like to know if it is *possible*, because it would certainly be handy in my case.

```
# drive1
storage -fstype=auto UUID="xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx"

# drive2
# This works (new mountpoint):
storage1 -fstype=auto UUID="yyyy-yyyy"
# This doesn't work (same mountpoint):
storage -fstype=auto UUID="yyyy-yyyy"
```

Answer (score 3):

It's certainly possible, in a number of different ways.

1) All automounter work by using `udev` rules which invoke programs or scripts. Find a automounter you like (`usbmount` is a simple one I prefer), and modify the scripts. Or write your own, using the existing scripts and rules as a template.

2) Give the volume (assuming a single volume) on each of the harddisks the same label or uuid (see `man tune2fs`), then use `/dev/disk/by-label/...` or `/dev/disk/by-uuid/...` to mount it in your preferred automounter (assuming it supports a configured path with a specific mountpoint).

And you should *definitely* think about what is going to happen if you accidentally attach both disks.